# How can I change my Elasticsearch query from multiple querys using _msearch to a single query using the bucket aggregation

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch.

Does anybody have an idea on how to change this query from an
currently _msearch query to an _search query?
It would also be convenient if I didn't have to make a separate query for every "CAR" but instead solve it with only one query. I would like to use the bucket aggregation instead.
This is my the query where I search for every Car separately:

```
GET /index/_msearch
{}
{"query": {"match": {"name": "CAR_RED"}},"size": 1,"sort": {"time":{"order": "desc"}}}
{}
{"query": {"match": {"name": "CAR_BLACK"}},"size": 1,"sort": {"time":{"order": "desc"}}}
{}
{"query": {"match": {"name": "CAR_WHITE"}},"size": 1,"sort": {"time":{"order": "desc"}}}
```

At the moment I am trying to solve it with the bucket aggregation but I always get an error.

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
      "CARS":{
        "terms":{"field":"name.keyword"}
      },
      "bucket_sort": {
        "sort": [
        {"time":{"order": "desc"}}
        ],
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

It would be awesome if anyone could help me with this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
    "query" : {"terms" : {"name.keyword" : ["CAR_RED","CAR_BLACK","CAR_WHITE"] }},
    "aggs" : {
      "CARS":{
        "terms":{"field":"name.keyword"},
        "aggs" : {
            "top_cars_by_time" : {
                 "top_hits" : {
                    "sort" : [
                       {
                          "time" : {order: "desc"}
                       }
                    ]
                 }
             }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What this query does:

Filters in the query itself, the RED,BLACK AND WHITE CARS

Aggregates the results by car color.
Then for each bucket in the aggregation, sorts the results by the descending order of the time field.
SO for every car color, you will get the hit with the greatest time first, and so on.

Read up on top_hits, its the aggregation you need.

[Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

HTH.